# Why if $f\in A[X]$ is reducible there is $f,g\in A[X]$ that are not invertible such that $f=gh$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $A$ a factorial ring. Why if $f\in A[X]$ is reducible there is $f,g\in A[X]$ that are not invertible such that $f=gh$. I don't understand in what $f,g$ can't be irreducible.

Comment: Some $f$'s may be messed up with $h$'s, I suppose. Otherwise, please state your definition of "reducible"

Comment: If $f(x)=x^4$, you cannot factor it into two irreducibles. You can factor it into two non-invertibles, though.

Comment: @Arthur You are wasteful - $f(x)=x^3$ would work as well :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I used $x^4$ because in that case you can even factor it into two non-irreducibles.